# Highlight JS Code in XML File (Eclipse)

Tags: javascript, html, xml, eclipse, syntax-highlighting

I am using Eclipse Juno (Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers). 
I've got 1 XML-File which contains XML, HTML and Javascript Code. (In this order.)
Before the HTML Code, there is an opening CDATA tag. From this point on there is no syntax highlightening anymore. When I delete the CDATA tag, only the HTML tags are highlighted.
I would like everything in this file to have syntax highlightening (expecially the JS Code).
Is this somehow possible?